# How do crop a picture on the new Facebook (2020)?

Tags: facebook

When I upload pictures to the new Facebook (2020 complete redesign) on a desktop browser, I see the options to crop and rotate then, but no way to save the changes. Going back to the previous page just warns me that the changes will be discarded.

Can someone please show me a screenshot of the new picture editor? I wonder if there's a save button that is hidden on my end because of some extension, or if there's another way to apply the edits.